Face property uneven texture with neighboring face
In babylonjs the checkerboard is just a null texture. Why though is it coming up uneven (losing continuity) at some points? It of course is noticeable with textures. Is that some face property? I thought it was the normals but it looks right (?) in the image below. I'm pretty new to blender, please let me know if I can include anything else.
Blender (left) Game Engine/Babylonjs (right)


I don't know about that game engine but have you actually unraveled the textures on blender and passed that information to the game engine somehow? If not, I assume the game engine is just going to do whatever with it, since it doesn't have any info and it's a blank texture. I don't think that's something wrong with the geometry of the model
